Issue with conditionals in empty matrix in github actions
I have a few output variables

has_changes
charts

I have tested that has_changes is false and charts is set to [], however in my if condition in the github action, its still trying to run my job even tho its false..

Here is example of my workflow
  get-chart:
    name: Get Chart Information  
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    outputs:
      has_changes: ${{ steps.get-chart.outputs.has_changes }}
      charts: ${{ steps.get-chart.outputs.charts }}

    steps:
      - id: get-chart
        run: |
          echo "charts=[]" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "has_changes=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  example:
    name: ${{ matrix.chart }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [get-chart]
    if: ${{ needs.get-chart.outputs.has_changes }}

    strategy:
      matrix: 
        chart: "${{ fromJSON(needs.get-chart.outputs.charts) }}"

my workflow is failing saying
Matrix vector 'chart' does not contain any values

I'm not too sure whats causing this as it appear to be setup correctly.. any advice?

I assume the part
    if: ${{ needs.get-chart.outputs.has_changes }}

is not checked correctly. I tried to reproduce your workflow and either you set the variable has_changes to an empty value, i.e.
          echo "has_changes=" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

or you change the if condition to something like
    if: ${{ needs.create_variable.outputs.has_changes != 'false' }}


Ran into the same issue today with release-please. Adding the explicit == 'true' to if: ${{ needs.release-please.outputs.releases_created == 'true' }} fixed it for me thanks to your answer. Makes sense in hindsight, if the value is a string it would always evaluate to true.
